# ¿Cual es el control más adecuado para mostrar datos tabulados en ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Que tal, voy a trabajar con algunos controles, y despues de buscar en algunos otros foros incluso en el mismo stackoverflow (ingles) llegue a la conclusion que la mayoria de las mismas son publicaciones muy antiguas.

Ahora bien lo que voy a trabajar son procesos de Windows (exe,bat etc) dentro de tablas para administrar sus procesos, ¿cual de los siguientes controles se adaptaría más al proyecto y por que? o ¿cual es el más nuevo?.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"></asp:DataList>
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server"></asp:DataPager>
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px"></asp:DetailsView>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"></asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Hola, creo que tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y difícil de responder porque depende mucho de las funcionalidades que necesites (ordenación de columnas, fijar filas, filtrado de datos, ...etc) En [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/05yye6k9(v=vs.100).aspx) artículo de la MSDN tienes una comparativa de GridView y DataGrid. Yo cuando he necesitado una "Grid" avanzada para WebForms he recurrido a controles de pago como Telerik y DevExpress (ahora en MVC los de Kendo UI)

Comment: Gracias @rsciriano muy interesante tu comentario.

Comment: De nada Matteo, encantado de poderte ayudar. Por cierto, al final me he lanzado y he añadido una respuesta aunque al final igual se acaba cerrando la pregunta, porque, como te decía, es demasiado amplia por lo que las respuestas se podrían basar en opiniones y ese no el propósito de S.O. Espero que te sirva de algo y te animo a cambiar WebForms por ASP.NET MVC. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para desplegar datos con formato de tabla el mejor control es el `GridView`

[GridView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Control GridView](http://www.tutorialesya.com.ar/aspnetya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=67)

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
  datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
  autogeneratecolumns="False"
  emptydatatext="No data available." 
  allowpaging="True" 
  runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Como veras defines `<asp:BoundField >` para indicar cada columna, por medio del `DataField` indica que propiedad o columna del origen de datos (datatable o lista que asignes al DataSource) mapea con esa columna del grid.

Comment: Muchas gracias @LeandroTuttini.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice [Leandro Tuttini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600/leandro-tuttini) en su respuesta, el mejor control de ASP.NET WebForms para mostrar datos en formato tabla (que viene directamente el Framework) es el [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx).

Realmente el control `GridView` es una evolución del antiguo control `DataGrid` por lo que, de los dos, es el más recomendable (como te decía en mi comentario, en [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/05yye6k9(v=vs.100).aspx) artículo de la MSDN se explican las diferencias entre ellos).

La cuestión es que puede haber casos en los que necesites tener más control del HTML que estás generando y por lo tanto tengas que recurrir a otros controles como el [DataList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist(v=vs.110).aspx) o el [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) en los se definen plantillas que se repiten a través del enlace a los datos.

```
<asp:ListView ID="VendorsListView"
    DataSourceID="VendorsDataSource"
    DataKeyNames="VendorID"
    runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <table cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1" ID="tbl1" runat="server">
        <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #98FB98">
          <th runat="server">ID</th>
          <th runat="server">Account Number</th>
          <th runat="server">Name</th>
          <th runat="server">Preferred Vendor</th>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
      </table>
      <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
        <Fields>
          <asp:NumericPagerField />
        </Fields>
      </asp:DataPager>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr runat="server">
        <td>
          <asp:Label ID="VendorIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VendorID") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:Label ID="AccountNumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountNumber") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></td>
        <td>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="PreferredCheckBox" runat="server" 
            Checked='<%# Eval("PreferredVendorStatus") %>' Enabled="False" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

La desventaja de hacer esto es que estás construyendo la tabla manualmente y puedes las funcionalidades de ordenación, paginación, ... que proporciona el control [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Como también te decía en mi comentario, cuando necesitas una tabla con funcionalidades avanzadas es conveniente recurrir a controles de pago como [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) o [DevExpress](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/) porque facilitan mucho la vida.

Por último, lo que te recomendaría es que, **si puedes**, te olvides de todos estos controles (y de WebForms) y hagas tu aplicación con [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) porque es la forma **más adecuada** de implementar aplicaciones Web con .NET, y también la **más moderna**.

La explicación de que los artículos que encontrabas en StackOverflow fueran antiguos es esta y además WebForms no va a estar soportado en ASP.NET Core, fíjate lo que dicen en este artículo (en inglés) [Porting to .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/)

> Less ideal for porting? If the majority of your web application is using WebForms, moving to ASP.NET Core is equivalent to a reimplementation as WebForms isn’t supported. However, if you want to use this as an opportunity to refactor your application anyways, this isn’t a show stopper as MVC/WebAPI is simply the more modern way to write web applications.

Comment: Exelente respuesta. muchas gracias por tu aporte de verdad,
en mi proximo proyecto tomare tu consejo.